# How to check for undefined before assigning to variable

Tags: typescript, angular5

Im using a find method to extract an ID (string) but this is returning an undefined as it doesnt exist.

```
const additionalLinePhoneNumber = products.find(product => product.name === 'segundaLinea').id;
```

Products has the following:

```
(2) [ProductInventoryList, ProductInventoryList]
0: ProductInventoryList {_id: "12345", _name: "lineaFija", _productInventoryCharacteristics: ProductInventoryCharacteristics}
1: ProductInventoryList {_id: "12345", _name: "primeraLinea", _productInventoryCharacteristics: ProductInventoryCharacteristics}
length: 2
```

So "segundaLinea" isnt returned so the find gives me the following error:

**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**

I tried doing this but doesnt work:

```
const additionalLinePhoneNumber = products.find(product => product.name === 'segundaLinea').id ? undefined : '';
```

What am I missing?

Trying the awnser below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) like this:

```
const additionalLinePhoneNumber = products.find(product => product.name === 'segundaLinea')?.id;
```

#### Edit:

For Typescript, the support for optional chaining was added with the [version 3.7](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33294). If you can't update your version you have to do it on multiple lines:

```
const segundaLinea = products.find(product => product.name === 'segundaLinea');
const additionalLinePhoneNumber = segundaLinea ? segundaLinea.id : "";
```

If you have to do this several times, you should probably write a helper function.

Comment: I have tried that also and it didnt work :(

Comment: @MONZTAAA you should try the example provided by Arkellys as it does work.

Comment: @MONZTAAA With the error you provided in your question I don't see how it could not work. Are you sure that the error comes from this line?

Comment: @MONZTAAA What version of Typescript are you using? If you have an old version you should try to update it.

Comment: 2.6.1 I cant update it, its not my own project.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to update, simply use optional(?) chaining

```
const segundaLinea = products.find(product => product?.name === 'segundaLinea');

const additionalLinePhoneNumber = segundaLinea?.id;
```